# Database Based Job scheduler

Tags: php, python, database

I need a job scheduler (a library) that queries a db every 5 minutes and, based on time, triggers events which have expired and rerun on failure.

It should be in Python or PHP.

I researched and came up with Advanced Python Scheduler but it is not appropriate because it only schedules the jobs in its job store. Instead, I want that it takes jobs from a database.

I also found Taskforest, which exactly fits my needs except it is a text-file based scheduler meaning the jobs have to be added to the text-file either through the scheduler or manually, which I don't want to do.

Could anyone suggest me something useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution
- a script, either in php or python performing your database tasks
- a scheduler : Cron for linux, or the windows task scheduler ; where you set the frequency of your jobs.
I'm using this solution for multiple projects.

Very easy to set up.

Comment: Cron can be a possible solution, but watch out for "lapping". If your job takes long time, longer than the frequency of starts, the same script can run at the same time as different processes. In this case the time taken by the script is increases.

Comment: I don't want to build a scheduler at first. I will try to it as the last resort if something like what i asked is available please tell me about it

Comment: You don't build a scheduler, you use the scheduler used by your webhost. Basically you set the frequency parameters, you point to your command line / script and that's all :)

Answer (score 0):

[Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) runs best using RabbitMQ, but also has support for databases, using [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

Comment: Can you please elaborate your solution a little. I tried going through the documentation of Celery but didn't got much